# Reference Sharepoint List with Excel Lookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-list

I'd like to use something similar to an excel lookup function to reference specific information in specific records of a sharepoint list. Sort of like the new IMAGE function references from a website address. Is there a way to reference specific record information from within excel?

I have previously linked the entirety of the sharepoint list with a query, but I'd prefer not to have this large of a data dump in the excel file for data security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

1. Under the "Data" in the ribbon in Excel, select "Get Data" > From Other Sources > From SharePoint List
2. Copy & Paste the SharePoint URL to the input box "Site URL" (Note: This must be the root URL for the site, not including subfolders)

This should pull the data in as a refreshable data table that you can reference elsewhere in the spreadsheet.

edit: you can use the power query window to add filters to trim the dataset so it isn't the entirety of it. Play around in the ribbon and you'll see several options which will create a new step in the query to edit the output. It can be as small as resorting or as big as structural changes to the data formulaically.

Comment: I've tried this before, and I don't want the entire database in my excel file. I'd like to link directly to the information on sharepoint.

Comment: In the Power query, you can simply filter whatever you need, even using dynamic filters like "Previous 3 years & Current Year"